# scipy.linalg.norm different from sklearn.preprocessing.normalize?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, norm, scikit-learn

```
from numpy.random import rand
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.linalg import norm

w = (rand(1,10)<0.25)*rand(1,10)
x = (rand(1,10)<0.25)*rand(1,10)
w_csr = csr_matrix(w)
x_csr = csr_matrix(x)
(normalize(w_csr,axis=1,copy=False,norm='l2')*normalize(x_csr,axis=1,copy=False,norm='l2')).todense()

norm(w,ord='fro')*norm(x,ord='fro')
```

I am working with scipy csr_matrix and would like to normalize two matrices using the frobenius norm and get their product. But norm from scipy.linalg and normalize from sklearn.preprocessing seem to evaluate the matrices differently. Since technically in the above two cases I am calculating the same frobenius norm shouldn't the two expressions evaluate to the same thing? But I get the following answer:

matrix([[ 0.962341]])

0.4431811178371029

for sklearn.preprocessing and scipy.linalg.norm respectively. I am really interested to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklearn.prepocessing.normalize` *divides* each row by its norm.  It returns a matrix with the same shape as its input.  `scipy.linalg.norm` returns the norm of the matrix.  So your calculations are not equivalent.

Note that your code is not correct as it is written.  This line

```
(normalize(w_csr,axis=1,copy=False,norm='l2')*normalize(x_csr,axis=1,copy=False,norm='l2')).todense()
```

raises `ValueError: dimension mismatch`.  The two calls to `normalize` both return matrices with shapes (1, 10), so their dimensions are not compatible for a matrix product.  What did you do to get `matrix([[ 0.962341]])`?

Here's a simple function to compute the Frobenius norm of a sparse (e.g. CSR or CSC) matrix:

```
def spnorm(a):
    return np.sqrt(((a.data**2).sum()))
```

For example,

```
In [182]: b_csr
Out[182]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [183]: b_csr.A
Out[183]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  1.]])

In [184]: spnorm(b_csr)
Out[184]: 5.0990195135927845

In [185]: norm(b_csr.A)
Out[185]: 5.0990195135927845
```

Comment: oh I see. So in that case I guess my question would be how do I replicate norm(w,ord='fro')*norm(x,ord='fro') using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize? I am using normalize instead of linalg.norm be cause it does not work on csr_matrix (sparse matrix) and you need to do csr_matrix.todense() before taking the norm in linalg.norm. So any help would be appreciated